# angular client side form validation in rails form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, validation

I am trying to do client side validations of a devise register form using angular. But I am unable to make it work. I am successfully getting the "invalid" class added to the fields as expected. But when I do ng-show Its now showing anything regardless of the class. There is no angular controllers or files other than this. All I am doing is clientside validation. All I added now is `ng-required` in `first_name` field. Could someone tell me what am doing wrong here?

Here is my code.

```
<div class="contaner-fluid" ng-app>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: {name: "myform", "novalidate" => true}) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div class="col-md-8  col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h2>Sign up</h2></div>
        <div class="panel-body">

          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
                  <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, "ng-model" => "myform.firstname", "ng-required": true, class: "form-control input-lg" %>
                </div>
                <p ng-show="myform.firstname.$invalid">
                  You must fill a valid name
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
                  <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control input-lg"%>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :email %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control input-lg" %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" , class: "form-control input-lg" %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control input-lg"  %>
          </div>

          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-success btn-block" %>
          </div>
<% end %>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

</div>
```

Here is my bower file

```
"dependencies": {
    "normalize-css": "normalize.css#~3.0.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.6",
    "angular": "~1.4.8",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.6"
  }
```

**Update**

I can do data binding..So angular is working fine in the form. If I try this it will work `{{myform.firstname}}`. But it wont show anything if I do `{{myform.firstname.$valid}}`..I can see that classes are added to input field but can't access it like this. I didnt created a `controller` or `module` as this is a very basic implementation. Thank you for the help.

Here is the full generated html for the form

```
<div class="contaner-fluid ng-scope" ng-app="">

<form name="myform" novalidate="novalidate" class="new_user ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="new_user" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="omiBCucx+U4r9P+T0d4rQEeKhni3H4YlSPSU9FIiP4yFnMe+orTnE64czY5NSk4Yd/8ObjPFz8mlURYgOfxXhw==">

    <div class="col-md-8  col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h2>Sign up</h2></div>
        <div class="panel-body">

          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 ng-binding">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="user_first_name">First name</label><br>
                  <input autofocus="autofocus" ng-model="myform.first_name" ng-required="true" class="form-control input-lg ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" type="text" name="user[first_name]" id="user_first_name" required="required">
                </div>

                <p ng-show="myform.first_name.$invalid" class="ng-hide">
                  You must fill a valid name
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="user_last_name">Last name</label><br>
                  <input autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="user[last_name]" id="user_last_name">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user_email">Email</label><br>
            <input autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control input-lg" type="email" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user_password">Password</label>
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-lg" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user_password_confirmation">Password confirmation</label><br>
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-lg" type="password" name="user[password_confirmation]" id="user_password_confirmation">
          </div>

          <div class="actions">
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
          </div>

</div>
</div>
</div></form>
  <a href="/users/sign_in">Log in</a><br>







</div>
```

Comment: You should actually add the `name` attribute in your form tag. I'm not sure if Rails adds a name to form tag or not, but you should make the form tag like <form name='myForm'>

Comment: 'html: {name: "myform", "novalidate" => true}'

Comment: You also need `name` for inputs to be correct. <input name='firstname'>.

Comment: verified that now..but that doesnt seem to be the issue

Comment: @ArashM Updated the question with the generated html.

Comment: The name attribute is `name="user[first_name]"`. It should be `name='first_name'` to be able to call it like `myform.first_name`. Also ng-model is not needed to be similar to form name. just use `ng-model='first_name'` then evaluate `myform` as the form object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100920/discussion-between-arash-m-and-abhilash).

Comment: tried that when u mentioned before so i changed it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the input's ng-model like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, "ng-model" =>  "firstname", "ng-required": true, class: "form-control input-lg" %>
```

Then change your `ng-show`:

```
<p ng-show="myform['user[first_name]'].$invalid">
```

and it should work.

P.S. you don't need to use `ng-required` since you're not evaluating requirement of the field. You can just use the html `required`.